# Is there a way to prefix all of the functions in a python module?

Tags: python

I have a module called foo.py from which another module bar.py loads the functions into its namespace. How can I prefix all of the functions in foo.py with the string `foo_`. An example:

foo.py:

```
def func1():
  return "hello"

def func2():
  return "world"
```

bar.py:

```
from foo import *

def do_something():
  return foo_func1()
```

Comment: Why not just `import foo` and then do `foo.func1()`? It's the correct way to use modules and seems very similar to what you're after.

Comment: Don't use star imports, then you won't have this name collision problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386714/why-is-import-bad

Comment: `Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!` -- [The Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/).

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
def do_something( i ):
    import foo
    f = getattr( foo, 'func'+str(i) )
    return f()

print( do_something(1) )  # hello
print( do_something(2) )  # world
```

you can access an attribute via string by using the oldfashion `getattr`-function. This will take a object and a `string`, which you can create during runtime.

> docs: [getattr(object, name[, default])](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#getattr)

---

**EDIT** (sorry, completely missread the question)

you can simply use

```
import foo
```

and then call the functions with:

```
foo.funct1()  # hello
foo.funct2()  # world
```